# Algebra question from HK Math Preliminary Contest 2020

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, absolute-value

The contest has already concluded more than 6 months ago. I am trying to figure out a smart way to solve the following question below:
Let $k$ be an integer. If the equation
$$(x-1)|x+1|=x + \frac{k}{2020}$$
has 3 distinct real roots, how many different possible values of $k$ are there?

Here is my initial try:
I have split the LHS using test point to get the piece wise function as below:
for $x\geq1$:
$$
x^2-1 = x + \frac{k}{2020},
$$
for $x<-1$:
$$
x^2 -1 = -\left(x+ \frac{k}{2020}\right).
$$
Plotting the LHS as upward opening parabola shifted down by 1 units and RHS as 2 straight lines with slope $+1$ and $-1$ with $y$-intercept of $\frac{k}{2020}$ and $-\frac{k}{2020}$.
To meet the 3 solutions criteria, the parabola cuts the positively sloped line at 2 points while being tangent to the line at $x=-1/2$ with negative slope.

How should I graphically get to the solution from here?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For framing your mathmatical expressions, please use MathJax. If you haven't learnt it yet, then please use this site https://www.mathcha.io/editor.

Answer (score 2):

The function $$f(x)=(x-1)|x+1|-x$$
passes through any horizontal line three times provided that the horizontal line is in the range of $y\in(-\frac54,1)$.  Therefore, it suffices to find the number of integers $k$ such that $-\frac54<\frac k{2020}<1.$

Solving the inequality, we get $$-2525<k<2020$$ and we see that $k$ can take on any one of $\boxed{4544}$ integers.